# Is it possible to train keras models on many training sets in a multiprocessed way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multiprocessing

I run python v=3.6.7 with PyCharm using a conda virtual environment. My tensorflow version is 1.12.0.
I want to train many keras models on various training sets. Since the training on one single training set is already quite slow, I would like to run the for loop using the Pool function of the multiprocessing library.
I provide below a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

fit_model is the function on which I want to run multiprocessing: it takes as an input a numpy array which is a training set and train a simple keras neural network on it (dummy settings).
I read already that one important aspect when performing multiprocessing with tensorflow is to make sure the function that we want to multiprocess has the tensorflow imports on the top, which is what I did. 
If I add the following instruction (below the "normal" imports)

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

on top of the fit_model function, I have the error message (truncated):

```
    ValueError: optimizer must be an instance of tf.train.Optimizer, not a <class 'str'>
```

Without the "enable_eager_execution" instruction, I get the following:

```
    multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: 
    '[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x00000184FFBAC630>]'. Reason: 'NotImplementedError('numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.',)'
```

Please see below my code. You can add little dummy training sets provided below: just drop the data in txt files 'ts1.txt', 'ts2.txt', 'ts3.txt' and save them where you run the code.

Training set 1:

```
    0.041495488 0.297990987 0.724621927 6.129053462
    0.953892097 0.308757758 0.469787044 5.969195238
    0.337488    0.49381137  0.906903059 13.21446917
    0.654812999 0.64815423  0.444301154 9.372944825
    0.119398718 0.152801516 0.59553224  2.786747848
    0.811252373 0.496546    0.899673501 14.13092453
    0.255991654 0.1058905   0.595081192 2.276359761
    0.715703318 0.391053934 0.077776996 2.283026639
    0.404416543 0.348081104 0.439224169 5.08963083
    0.076034482 0.285709566 0.43068089  3.597459163
```

Training set 2:

```
    0.351528844 0.866463242 0.083273802 2.723360975
    0.689580826 0.875736673 0.783812364 20.59873213
    0.756136259 0.717057395 0.455913086 10.66591631
    0.133306324 0.418013101 0.023300008 0.539324484
    0.948773896 0.253098491 0.455538012 5.125835331
    0.41842445  0.518841476 0.475774703 7.74869507
    0.535329652 0.548263348 0.37085254  6.763755249
    0.665158688 0.501906321 0.031474934 1.772646491
    0.30009976  0.649788342 0.685829413 13.07823033
    0.15021059  0.806372521 0.853050268 19.56095746
```

Training set 3:

```
    0.990594623 0.229487172 0.28671828  3.823537929
    0.941261097 0.87953271  0.384903849 11.3615169
    0.260536935 0.889700723 0.456944222 11.90429481
    0.543933952 0.683776861 0.269533461 6.248288724
    0.287850026 0.464306966 0.698678531 9.658936707
    0.260487811 0.569814545 0.050767667 1.33096397
    0.836448581 0.642146809 0.350982713 7.98360518
    0.437645129 0.87036494  0.638338969 16.4317503
    0.88084079  0.943387589 0.564804696 16.6809143
    0.859626262 0.453784697 0.951882406 13.81384327
```

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy

def fit_model(dataset):
        from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
        from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
        #import tensorflow as tf
        #tf.enable_eager_execution()
        x = dataset[:, 0:3]
        y = dataset[:, 3]
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(x, y, epochs=3)
        return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
        dataset1 = numpy.loadtxt('ts1.txt')
        dataset2 = numpy.loadtxt('ts2.txt')
        dataset3 = numpy.loadtxt('ts3.txt')
        datasets = [dataset1, dataset2, dataset3]

        p = Pool()
        models_mp = p.map(fit_model, datasets)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

The code above does not work and I start to wonder if I what I am trying to do is actually possible.

Comment: Do you have CUDA support on your machine? If the code runs on GPU you need to have multiple GPUs, not CPUs in order to speed up execution.

Comment: My machine is not CUDA enabled unfortunately. I don’t have a NVIDIA graphic card. Does it mean there’s no way of speeding up these learnings? Thanks.

Comment: There is, multiple computers. But if you have no CUDA, than your CPU is fully loaded anyway for model training so multiprocessing will not change anything. You may use cloud providers, some are free for a while/cheap, GPU will definitely help your case the most.

Comment: Even if I have 8 cores? I would have naively thought I could have dispatched the trainings among the cores to split the work?

Comment: Check your core usage, most of them are running training on one dataset anyway. But in principle you could, not through multiprocessing though. It will not help though